# Помогите расшифровать код

Tags: кодировка, шифрование, режимы-шифрования

Помогите узнать что за шифр в этом сообщении

```
РЎРѕРѕР±С‰РµРЅРёРµ СѓРґР°Р»РµРЅРѕ, СЂРµРґР°РєС‚РёСЂРѕРІР°РЅРёРµ РЅРµРІРѕР·РјРѕР¶РЅРѕ.
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что вопрос поставлен некорректно. У Вас скорее всего кодировка слетела. Внесите подробностей: откуда это у Вас и зачем.

Answer (score 2):

Это не шифр, просто вы просматриваете сообщение не в той кодировке

```bsh
echo 'РЎРѕРѕР±С‰РµРЅРёР...' | iconv -t cp1251 -f utf8
```

`Сообщение удалено, редактирование невозможно`

Comment: Ага. Сразу же по этим буквам видно, что с ними... ;)